# Rails gem jwt_sessions logout unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

Registration and login work fine.In cookies and localStorage csrf is added.But when I try to logout gives an error 401

**Signin Controller:**

```
class SigninController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_access_request!, only: [:destroy]

  def create
    user = User.find_by!(email: params[:email])

    if user.authenticate(params[:password])
      payload = { user_id: user.id }
      session = JWTSessions::Session.new(payload: payload, refresh_by_access_allowed: true)
      tokens = session.login

      response.set_cookie(JWTSessions.access_cookie,
                          value: tokens[:access],
                          httponly: true,
                          secure: Rails.env.production?)
      render json: { csrf: tokens[:csrf]}
    else
      not_authorized
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session = JWTSessions::Session.new(payload: payload)
    session.flush_by_access_payload
    render json: :ok
  end

  private

  def not_found
    render json: { error: 'Cannot find such email/password combination' }, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

I receive this error

**Error:**

```
Started DELETE "/signin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-12 21:56:17 +0300
    (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
    ↳ /home/greifrut/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by SigninController#destroy as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you post your `authorize_access_request!` method. Also, are you sure you’re actually sending your token headers when you sign out?

Comment: Authorize_access_request! standart method in jwt_session gems. The deletion a session was documented and the same code is functioning in another app